# MongoDB aggregate queries

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to query my database for a set of values, but instead of obtaining the values themselves, I want the product of the value and the value of another document (with different requirements) closest in date. Here's how I'm currently doing it with `n + 1` queries:

```
Model.find({
  user: user1,
  date: { $gte: start, $lte: end }
}, 'date value', (err, results) => {
  results.forEach(e => {
    Model.find({
      user: user2,
      date: { $gte: e.date }
    }, 'value').sort({ date: 1 }).limit(1).exec((err, matched) => {
      e.value *= matched[0].value;
    });
  });
});
```

So I want the values within a range of dates associated with `user1`, each multiplied by the value of the closest document (in date) associated with `user2`. There is no guarantee the dates for the documents for `user1` and `user2` will be exactly the same, so I'm using a combination of `$gte`, sorting, and limiting to obtain the closest (I know it's not exact since there can be a closer date earlier than it, but this is good enough).

I'm thinking there must be a way to do this with `aggregate`. I was looking into using `$lookup` to join the values from the corresponding documents for each user, but without a field that matches exactly I don't see how I can do that.

Am I on the right track? There has to be a better way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query in 3.6

Use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#lookup-syntax-let-pipeline) let syntax.

```
Model.aggregate([
  {"$match":{
      "user": user1,
        "date": {"$gte":start, "$lte":end}
  }}, 
  {"$lookup":{
    "from": collectionname, use collection name here
    "let": {"date":"$date"},
    "pipeline":[
      {"$match":{ 
        "user": user2, 
        "$expr":{"$gte":["$date","$$date"]}
      }},
     {"$sort":{"date": 1}},
     {"$limit":1},
     {"$project":{"value":1}}
    ],
    "as": "lookup-data"
  }},
  {"$project":{
    "date":1, 
    "value":{
     "$multiply":[
       "$value", {
         "$let":{
           "vars":{"lookupdata":{"$arrayElemAt":["$lookup-data",0]}},
            "in":"$$lookupdata.value"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: oh I should have mentioned I'm on Mongo v3.2.17, so the lookup syntax is a little different. I'll see if I can figure it out though

Comment: You will need to update mongo server to 3.6 to use the new lookup syntax.

Comment: I thought $lookup was available in 3.2, is it not possible to rewrite this code using the old syntax?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to re-write using lookup syntax in  3.2 which is for equality matches. I have used the lookup with pipeline syntax from 3.6 which takes the pipeline and you can perform more complex operations on joined collection.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with 3.2 lookup syntax, it is just quite inefficient:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {$match: {user: user1, date:{$gte: start, $lte: end)}}},
    {$addFields: {anotherUser: user2}},
    {$lookup: {
       from: "collection",
       localField: "anotherUser",
       foreignField: "user",
       as: "anotherUser"
    }},     
    {$project: {
        user:1,
        date:1,
        value: {$let: {
            vars: {         
                anotherUser: {$let: {
                    vars: {
                        all: {$filter: { 
                            input: "$anotherUser", 
                            as: "au", 
                            cond: {$gte: ["$$au.date", "$date"]} 
                        }}
                    },
                    in: { $let: {
                        vars: {
                            minDate: {$min:  "$$all.date"}
                        },
                        in: { $arrayElemAt: [ 
                            {$filter: { 
                                input: "$$all", 
                                as: "su", 
                                cond: {$eq: ["$$su.date", "$$minDate"]} 
                            }},
                            0
                        ]}
                    }}
                }}
            },
            in: {$multiply: ["$value", "$$anotherUser.value"] }
        }}
     }}     
])
```

The `$lookup` stage adds all `user2` documents into `anotherUser` field for each `user1` document. It is then filtered by date, and eventually resolved to a single value of course, but it happens only on the next `$project` stage. On large datasets `$lookup` stage can easily exhaust [100MB limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-limits/#memory-restrictions).

I didn't test the performance. It might be that your original multi-query approach is even quicker than such pipeline if you have proper indexes by user and date. It is definitely uses less memory than the aggregation and is way more readable/testable/maintainable.